Apache Druid - Ingest Microsoft SQL Server Data
Trying to ingest data from SQL Server into the Apache Druid (30.0.0)
Testing connection to extenal db using the SQL Panel
E.g. Query
SELECT * FROM TABLE(
  EXTERN(
    '{
      "type": "sql",
      "database": {
        "type": "sqlserver",
        "connectorConfig": {
          "connectURI": "jdbc:sqlserver://<SQL_SERVER_HOST>:<SQL_SERVER_PORT>;databaseName=<DATABASE_NAME>",
          "user": "<USERNAME>",
          "password": "<PASSWORD>"
        }
      },
      "sqls": ["SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>"]
    }',
    '{"type":"json"}',
    '[{"name":"__time","type":"long"}]'
  )
)

Getting the error

Convert your_data_source_name



Connect external data





Run

Engine: sql-msq-task

Max tasks: 2 (full cluster capacity)


Error: INVALID_INPUT

Invalid value for the field [inputSource]. Reason: [Please make sure to load all the necessary 
extensions and jars with type 'sqlserver' on 'druid/broker' service. Could not resolve type id 
'sqlserver' as a subtype of `org.apache.druid.metadata.SQLFirehoseDatabaseConnector` known type ids 
= [] (for POJO property 'database') at [Source: (String)"{ "type": "sql", "database": { "type": 
"sqlserver", "connectorConfig": { "connectURI": "jdbc:sqlserver://<SQL_SERVER_HOST>:
<SQL_SERVER_PORT>;databaseName=<DATABASE_NAME>", "user": "<USERNAME>", "password": "<PASSWORD>" } 
}, "sqls": ["SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>"] }"; line: 4, column: 17] (through reference chain: 
org.apache.druid.metadata.input.SqlInputSource["database"])]


Have download the JAR's as detailed here and enabled in the conf for common.runtime.properties.
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-contrib/sqlserver/
